# Formula for combinations with constraints?

Tags: math, combinations, combinatorics

Suppose we have 4 bags (A, B, C, and D) having number of balls in them as (a, b, c, and d,  respectively.) Let r<sub>a</sub>, r<sub>b</sub>, r<sub>c</sub> and r<sub>d</sub> be the number of balls selected from each bag.

I'd like to impose constraints on the number of balls in each bag (say, like r<sub>a</sub> < r<sub>c</sub>, r<sub>b</sub> < r<sub>c</sub>, r<sub>d</sub> ≤ r<sub>c</sub>, etc.) Also, the balls in each bag are numbered, so xi(n)r<sub>i</sub> represents the number of combinations possible of choosing r balls from the bag i, which contains xi balls in total

Is there any way to calculate the number of ways possible to choose the balls abiding these constraints?

I know I could solve this by writing some code. However, I'm looking for a simple formula for the answer. Without the constraints, there would be 2<sup>n</sup> possibilities, but with the constraints there would be fewer. The normal combinations formula (nCr) is irrelevant because of the other constraints added in, and I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: To me this sounds more math than programming

Comment: Yes that’s true. Was wondering if someone could help in this because the worst case time complexity which would be acceptable is O(NlogN) so I think a mathematical calculation would be better.

Comment: There is also https://math.stackexchange.com/, but I don't know exactly what's the scope of that -- but might be better suited there.

Comment: I posted it there too... just wanted to be sure that in case if there is a programming angle to this question then that too gets explored!